# symfony mongodb odm referenceMany

Tags: mongodb, symfony, odm

Hi experts: I have a problem building a query to extract details of the document that has been referenced using 'referenceMany'. Here is the example setup of the code

```
class FoodItem{

    /**
    * @MongoDb\Id
    */
    protected Id;

   /**
   * @MongoDb\field(type="string")
   */
    protected name;

    /**
    * @MongoDb\field(type="float")
    */
    protected calories;

    /**
    * @MongoDb\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="FoodItem", storeAs="id")
    */
    protected $bestEatenWith = array();
}
```

The idea is 1 FoodItem can be bestEatenWith other FoodItems, therefore 'bestEatenWith' is an array of 'Id's belonging to the same 'FoodItem' document.

The query I used is as follows -

```
    $qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('AppBundle:FoodItem')
        ->select("name", "bestEatenWith", "nutrition")
        ->eagerCursor(true)
        ->hydrate(false);
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $result = $query->execute();
```

The result I get is then displayed using Twig template, and I can display in Twig, the 'name' and 'nutrition', but I get 'bestEatenWith' as an array of 'Id's

**Question 1:** How do I parse through the $result using PHP and access the 'Id's contained in the array of 'bestEatenWith' ?

**Question 2:** Can I not possibly get something like 'bestEatenWith.name' in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mohamed for your answer, you have answered part of my question. However I have the found the answer myself to the second part so that makes it a full answer.

Here is what I did-

**Answer 1**

1. Used dump() as Mohamed answered

**Answer 2**

1. Use the getter function 'getBestEatenWith' to retrieve the array
2. Then used the foreach and used the getter function like getName to retrieve the name of bestEatenWith record

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**

In the controller dump the result with the `dump` function:

```
dump($result);
```

**Question 2**

Normally you can getting the name from `bestEatenWith` exists in `$result`